Rendering sometimes blocks when updating Index Buffer at runtime
I developed a way to update my index buffer at run-time in Vulkan. Unfortunately, sometimes the rendering process blocks. I think that is caused by the update of the index buffer. The following code shows the creation and the update of the index buffer:
void Renderer::CreateIndexBuffer()
{
        VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].indices[0]) 
        * engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].indices.size();

        engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBuffers.resize(engineRenderer.MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
        engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBufferMemories.resize(engineRenderer.MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);
        engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBuffersMapped.resize(engineRenderer.MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < engineRenderer.MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT; i++) {
            engineRenderer.CreateBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_INDEX_BUFFER_BIT, 
            VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, 
            engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBuffers[i], 
            engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBufferMemories[i]);

            vkMapMemory(engineDevice.logicalDevice, engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBufferMemories[i], 0,
            bufferSize, 0, &engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBuffersMapped[i]);
        }
 }   




void Renderer::UpdateIndexBuffer()
{
        VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].indices[0]) * 
        engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].indices.size();
        memcpy(engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].meshBuffer.indexBuffersMapped[currentFrame], 
        engineModLoader.sceneMeshes[0].indices.data(), (size_t) bufferSize);
        
}

Where am I going wrong?

did you check the documentation, especially the usage section?
https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdUpdateBuffer.html
